# How to move columns whose sum is negative to the end?

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

for example: i have an array:

```
int[][] arr = {{-3,1,-5,2,-1},
               {-3,1,-5,2,-2},
               {-3,1,-5,2,-3}};
```

and i need to get such an array:

```
int[][] arr = {{1,2,-3,-5,-1},
               {1,2,-3,-5,-2},
               {1,2,-3,-5,-3}};
```

I want the program to be universal for any double arrays.

---

any thoughts?

Comment: Start at column 0, compute the sum of the column.  If it's less than 0, find a column to the right that has a positive sum.  Swap the two columns.  Move to column 1 and do the same thing until you reach the last column.

Comment: Do you care about order of positive values? Would be much easier if you can just use natural order (`2,1,-1,-3,-5`) instead of `1,2,-3,-5,-1`.

Comment: Vandalizing your own posts (as by replacing their titles or contents with garbage) is against the rules here.

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to do it.  This will only work for rectangular arrays since one could not possibly maintain column alignment if any positive summed column was shorter than a negative summed column.

```
int[][] arr = { { -3, 1, -5, 2, -1 },
                { -3, 1, -5, 2, -2 },
                { -3, 1, -5, 2, -3 } };
```

First create a single array of column sums.

```
int[] colsum = new int[arr[0].length];

for (int col = 0; col < arr[0].length; col++) {
    for (int row = 0; row < arr.length; row++) {
           colsum[col] += arr[row][col];
    }       
}
```

Then, create a result array to copy the columns based on the column sums.
To preserve relative column order of same signed columns, two loops are used.  The first goes from right to left.  The second goes from left to right but also stops once the previously added negative columns are reached.

```
int[][] result = new int[arr.length][arr[0].length];

int rearLoc = arr[0].length-1;
int forwardLoc = 0;
for (int col = arr[0].length-1; col >= 0; col--) {
    if (colsum[col] < 0) {
         for (int row = 0; row < arr.length; row++) {
               result[row][rearLoc] = arr[row][col];
         }
         rearLoc--;
    }
}
for (int col = 0;  forwardLoc <= rearLoc && col < arr[0].length; col++) {
    if (colsum[col] >= 0) {
        for (int row = 0; row < arr.length; row++) {
            result[row][forwardLoc] = arr[row][col];
        }
        forwardLoc++;
    }
}
for (int[] a : result) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
}
```

Prints

```
[1, 2, -3, -5, -1]
[1, 2, -3, -5, -2]
[1, 2, -3, -5, -3]
```

Comment: yes it's working, but is there any ways to make the sequence of negative numbers look like mine in the example? Like the original sequence of negative numbers should be preserved, but here it changes

Comment: I modified my answer and explanation.   I had to use two loops, first right to left and left to right.  The second loop does not always have to traverse the entire source array.

Comment: if i add to array one more column with 3,3,3 the program outpots 3 zeros not 3 threes, but it's still working. How can I fix this?

Comment: I apologize.  When I updated my answer I made a dumb mistake.   In the second outer loop, change `col < arr[0].length-1` to `col < arr[0].length`.  It worked before because there was no positive sum in the last column so there was no need for the loop to reach it.

Comment: ha-ha thank you, I literally wanted to write this, I couldn't think how to change arr[0].length-1.